# YANDEX API Open a geopoint which is not shown

Tags: javascript, maps, yandex, yandex-api

I'm trying to open a balloon of a geopoint which is not shown. The official api docs says

> if the point is show then open it or it's cluster balloon

but how do I open it if it's not shown? I tried to scroll the map to it's position and then open it, but I'm still getting an error `TypeError: this._Hh.getMap(...) is null` when opening the balloon.

```
function bymShowPoint(pId)
{

    var point = bymGetPoint(pId);
    var pState = bymClusterer.getObjectState(point);

    if (!pState.isShown)
    {

        bymScrollToPoint(pId);

    }

    if (pState.isClustered)
    {

        pState.cluster.state.set('activeObject',point);
        pState.cluster.balloon.open();

    }

    else
    {

        point.balloon.open();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API doesn't let you to open a non-visible point's balloon if the point is in a cluster.
The way I've solved it (with the help of the yandex community) is:

1. open the map's balloon at the point's position with the point's data
2. remove the point from the clusterer (to hide the icon)
3. on the map's event `balloonclose` add the removed point to the clusterer